# how to resize a window height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that lists some books. When an user scrolls to page bottom, the list will append more books by `ajax`. And there are 3 tabs to switch book catalogs. The list may get very long making the window scroll deeply, then if the user clicks another tab, I will remove the lists DOM element and make a new one, send a new `ajax` to append new items.

**But the page keeps at the deep bottom and the new adding items are appearing at the top of the `window`**. There is no way to see the new ones without scrolling to the top of the `window`. So if there is a way to solve this problem, for example resize the window height to screen height? I try `window.resizeTo`, however, this is not working. How can I make it like a reloading page?

[image]

Comment: Why not just scroll the window back to the top? You can do with with pure JS if you're comfortable or jQuery. Quick googling will give you the code.

Comment: But there may be a large blank space at the page of the bottom. What's more, only if an user scrolls to the bottom can the page sends a new ajax to request more data. With large blank space, this can't trigger to ask for data.

Comment: You still want to scroll the window to the top because that's where the new data is located. Then you should recalculate the height of the window if you are calculating manually. Really I think you shouldn't set the height of the window with JS if that's what you're doing. It's hard to help you solve the problem without any code examples. Please try to put together a code sample for us to work from.

Comment: Thank you for help. I finally got the reason. See the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the reason:

The normal behavior of browsers will set the height to 0 if remove all its children. But in my browser I install an extension called "care your eye". It will automatically add two `divs`: ".cye-workaround-body" and ".cye-workaround-body-image" after the body tag, which causes the unusual style.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this.

```js
$(".add").on('click', function(){ 
    $(".new").append("<div class='added'>New Book</div>");
});
```

```css
.new{ height: auto}
.added{ min-height:100px; background-color:#A0A0A0; margin:10px; padding:5px;}
```

```html
<div class="new"></div>

<span class="add" style="background-color:#DEDEDE; padding:5px; cursor:pointer;">Add Another</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your inspiration. I finally got the reason! The normal behavior of browsers will set the height to 0 if remove all its children. But in my browser  I install an extension called "care your eye". It will automatically add two div ".cye-workaround-body" and ".cye-workaround-body-image" after the `body` tag, which causes the unnormal  style.